# How can I verify that JADE and IPMS are correctly installed

Tags: java, agent, agents-jade

My question is: as mentioned in the title, how I can verify that my JADE and inter-platform mobility service are correctly installed.

PS: I use JADE-4.3.3 and ipms-2.0-R1-jade3.7 ( I don't know if they are compatible to each-other)